# Can't change the screensaver on MacBook

Tags: ventura, screensaver

I have changed the screensaver on my MacBook Pro Ventura. However, it's not taking effect, even when I click on preview button it doesn't show the preview of selected screensaver. it shows preview of Ventura screen save only and that's all see as scree saver.

This is office laptop so not sure if there is a permission issue.

from command line also it shows that screen saver has been set.

```
defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver
{
    CleanExit = 1;
    PrefsVersion = 100;
    idleTime = 300;
    moduleDict =     {
        moduleName = Fliqlo;
        path = "/Users/fki/Library/Screen Savers/Fliqlo.saver";
        type = 0;
    };
    showClock = 0;
    tokenRemovalAction = 0;
}
```

This is what I found on my profiles managed by device.

[image][image]

Comment: If it's an office laptop, it may have been configured so that users can't alter things. Ask your IT department.

Comment: Or look in System Preferences > Profiles (System Settings > Privacy > Profiles on macOS Ventura or higher) and see if a computer-level profile is restricting that setting.  You might also want to make sure you have the latest version of that saver, or try a different third-party one.

Comment: I see lots of profiles. How do I know which profile is creating an issue . there are few in user managed and few in device managed.

Comment: The clue is in the name "device managed". You have a device that is managed, outside of normal user control.

Comment: is there anything I can do, I have sudo access.

Comment: sudo is not enough. You have a Mac whose settings are managed by your company. You cannot change this yourself.

Comment: how about if If I create a softlink, would that work ?